How to set up logging for just my code in Django
I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up a logger for just my app.  My app is named calibration.  This is what I have in settings.py

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO'
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cerfServer.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'calibration': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        }
    }
}


I assume that I create a logger with the same name as my app.  But this is not working.  I am not seeing my Debug messages.  If I set the root logger to DEBUG, then I do see the Debug messages, as well as for everything else such as Boto.  I want to leave Root set to Info and only see my Debug messages

logger need action.
# views.py
import logging
...
logger = logging.getLogger('calibration')
...
def some_view(*args):
  logger.debug({some message})
  ...


Yes, this is exactly what doesn't work.  I have logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) in all my views.  The app is named calibration.  But I'm not sure if I need to qualify it more in the settings.

Use explicitly the name of the logger you want to use, not __name__.
I think __name__ is getting str something other than the set logger name.
